# Unable to locate package php5-readline

Tags: 12.04, php

```
samitha@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-readline
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-readline
```

What would be the issue ?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 12.04 brother ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th package `php5-readline` is not present in `12.04` repository since the module is already packaged along with `php5`. Its only available in `Saucy` repository as a separate package as explained here in this [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~zanfur/+archive/php5.5).

```
N.B.: In the saucy packaging, unlike the precise packaging, 
the php5-cli interactive mode does *not* include the readline module built in.
You will have to install the new php5-readline package for "php -a" to function reasonably.
```

So if you have installed the `php5` then you just need to execute `php -a` to get `Interactive mode enabled`

This is the PPA, I use for php5

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu precise main
```